# Changing language in Fragments leading to Fragments entry point

Tags: android, android-fragments

**In activity using Fragments,**

> Fragments i navigated to some fragments screens.
> Now i will change the language from the settings.
>
> Issue: Application will resets to entry point of the Fragments Screen.

**Clarity on issue Faced:**

> Activity -  Fragments A > Fragment B > Fragments C > Fragment D.
> Now i navigated to Fragments C.
> Pressed home button.
> Changed the language under device settings.
> Issue is : After resuming the application - I am in the Fragments A.

**Raised ticket in Google issues as well :** https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189086

Here my problem & question is,
Is this really an issue or the Android standard behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is save the state of your app in the onPause method. After going back to the app, you should instantiate that saved fragment in the onResume method.

Comment: It is an issue in android OS itself, I did the huge research but didn't get the solution.
  I raised the issue to Google's Android community, They are working on it!!


 Reference: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189086

Comment: I will update the answer here as soon as the Google respond me with the fix!!